# How to limit Regex validation for Port number Validation 1024 to 65535

Tags: regex, validation, port

The port number should take only between 1024 to 65535 and should not accept any Zero value.
e.g 0000 , Should not accept. I spent almost an hr. to find it out so posting the answer as well.

Comment: Why not just check if the number is between 1024 & 65535?

Comment: MrBones - thats correct , the same thing can be achived by this code ^(102[4-9]|10[3-9]\d|1[1-9]\d{2}|[2-9]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])$

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. x >= 1024 && x <= 65535

Comment: yupp , the framework on which i am workign takes the code in regex , i cant do in that way.

Comment: Also you can use [this tool](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range)

Answer (score 2):

`^(102[4-9]|10[3-9]\d|1[1-9]\d{2}|[2-9]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])$`

The above code will allow you to accept port number between 1024 to 65535 and will not accept any 0000.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, *decomposition* (*aka* divide-and-conquer) — breaking complicated problems into smaller, simpler ones — is a good tool. So, let's break things down into simple regular expressions. Then we can combine them into the final solution. We can break this down by first noting that we have a range of 4-digit numbers (1024-9999) and a range of 5-digit numbers (10000-65535).

**4-digit numbers**

Within the range of 4-digit numbers, the low end of the range has some oddities that we need to handle, but we can break it out thusly into simple regular expressions:

```
1     0     2     [4-9] # matches 1024 - 1029
1     0     [3-9] [0-9] # matches 1030 - 1099
1     [1-9] [0-9] [0-9] # matches 1100 - 1999
[2-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] # matches 2000 - 9999: the general case
```

**5-digit numbers**

Similarly, the range of 5-digit numbers has some oddities at the high end of the range:

```
[1-5] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] # matches 10000 - 59999: the general case
6     [0-4] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] # matches 60000 - 64999
6     5     [0-4] [0-9] [0-9] # matches 65000 - 65499
6     5     5     [0-2] [0-9] # matches 65500 - 65529
6     5     5     3     [0-5] # matches 65530 - 65535
```

None of these are terribly complicated.

Regular expressions allow *grouping* with parenthesis and *alternation* (choice) with `|`. We can simply combine all of the above, drop some anchors at start and end of line and allow for leading zeros and you're done:

```
^                              # anchor match at start-of-line, followed by
0*                             # zero or more leading zeros
  (102[4-9])                   #  1,024 -  1,029
| (10[3-9][0-9])               #  1,030 -  1,099
| (1[1-9][0-9][0-9])           #  1,100 -  1,999
| ([2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])       #  2,000 -  9,999
| ([1-5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])  # 10,000 - 59,999
| (6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9])      # 60,000 - 64,999
| (65[0-4][0-9][0-9])          # 65,000 - 65,499
| (655[0-2][0-9])              # 65,500 - 65,529
| (6553[0-5])                  # 65,530 - 65,535
$                              # anchor match at end-of-line
```

Regular expression engines, by default, is greedy and matches according to the *leftmost longest" principle: it will find the longest possible match. If there are multiple possible longest matches of equal length, the leftmost match is preferred.

One should not that this regular expression will *backtrack*, meaning that it's not the most efficient form. To eliminate backtracking, you'd have to note that the subexpressions share common prefixes and you'll need to factor those out so the match is predicative. However, for validating short text fields, the performance should be quite sufficient. Further, I think this is probably simpler and easier to understand (for the next guy, who needs to change it.

If you want to learn how to polish your regular expressions and get the best performance out of them, you should read Jeffrey Friedl's opus, [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/book.html):

[image: Mastering Regular Expressions cover]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in an optimized way:

```
^(?:[2-5]\d{3,4}|1(?:[1-9]\d{2,3}|0(?:[3-9]\d{1,2}|[01]\d{2}|2(?:[4-9]\d?|[0-3]\d)))|6(?:[0-4]\d{2,3}|5(?:[0-4]\d{1,2}|5(?:[0-2]\d?|3[0-5]?|[4-9])|[6-9]\d)|[6-9]\d{2})|[7-9]\d{3})$
```

**How is it optimized?**

The idea is to build the pattern by putting the most probable alternative at first. *(for example, there are obviously more numbers that begin with `[2-5]` than numbers that begin with 1 or 6)*

The second optimization consists to build the pattern in a way the regex engine never has to go back. *(in other words, once the regex engine begin to find a match in a branch, you are sure that it doesn't need to test the other branches in the same alternation since it can succeed in this current branch)*

Result: you obtain a pattern a little longer, but faster *(however, the gain is light)*.

**indented version**

```
^
(?:
    [2-5]\d{3,4}              # 44000
  |
    1                         # 10976
    (?:
        [1-9]\d{2,3}               # 9900
      |
        0                          # 1076: 770, 200, 106:(66,40)
        (?: [3-9]\d{1,2} | [01]\d{2} | 2(?:[4-9]\d? | [0-3]\d) )
    )
  |
    6                         # 6536
    (?:
        [0-4]\d{2,3}                # 5500
      | 
        5                           # 636
        (?:
            [0-4]\d{1,2}                       # 550
          |
            5 (?: [0-2]\d? | 3[0-5]? | [4-9] ) # 46: 33, 7, 6
          |
            [6-9]\d                            # 40
        )
      |
        [6-9]\d{2}                  # 400
    )
  |
    [7-9]\d{3}                 # 3000
)$  # 64512 = 65535 - 1024 + 1
```